# Is regular conditional distribution unique?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

If $\kappa_1,\kappa_2:\mathfrak{B}\times\Omega\rightarrow\left[0,1\right]$ are two *regular* versions of the same conditional distribution $P\left(\left.X\in\cdot\right|\mathcal{A}\right)$, are they equal as functions?

Comment: @StefanHansen: For every $D\in\mathfrak{B}$, $\kappa_i(D,\cdot)$ is a version of $P(X\in D|\mathcal{A})$ and for every $\omega\in\Omega$, $\kappa_i(\cdot,\omega)$ is a probability on $\mathfrak{B}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then the answer is "no". Let $\mu$ be a Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ with Borel $\sigma$-algebra and consider two functions $f(x,y) = x$ and 
$$
  g(x,y) = 1(x\neq 1)f(x,y).
$$
Both functions imply the same joint distribution, but they are not equal.